# How to ensure custom css file called within WHMCS bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, whmcs

I am using a free WHMCS template and customising it to match the rest of my site. In the head.tpl file of my template i have included my additional stylesheets as per the standard procedure, and whereby the are showing in the source code, the styles are not being applied. I am guessing this is due to bootstrap being used? I have been hunting around for a while and cannot seem to pinpoint how i can include these external styles within bootstrap? Please can any one advise me how i may achieve this? Is there a file within the bootstrap framework i need to edit?

Best Regards

Donna

I have added the stylesheets into the head.tpl file in WHMCS as below:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{$BASE_PATH_CSS}/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{$BASE_PATH_CSS}/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styling -->
<link href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/overrides.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/slicknav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--External Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/css/small.desktop.css" media="(max-width: 1150px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/css/tablet.css" media="(max-width: 1030px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/css/small.tablet.css" media="(max-width: 820px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/css/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 580px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/css/override.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/templates/gk_simplicity/style1.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{$BASE_PATH_JS}/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/css/custom.css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As i said they are included in the source code of the page, but the syle is not being applied?

Comment: You should list the Bootstrap CSS file before your own custom CSS file. Can you show us the way you linked them to your document?

Comment: @RachelS I have added the code from my head.tpl file above.

Comment: What about adding rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" where you added custom.css?

Comment: Did you update the code for Six template? If your styles are for your website, probably it will not just apply for the Six elements the same way for your website. For example the <nav id="nav" does your css style this element differently?